# Nginx enable directory listing if file exists and enable basic auth if another file exists

Tags: nginx

I'm developing a site where users can upload file through FTP and they can see those file on an HTTPS link.

I want them to be able to

- 1, Enable directory listing in a specific directory by putting a simple 'enabledirlisting.txt' file
- 2, Enable basic auth by putting 'userpasswordfile.txt' (the basic auth file being that file)

Something like this:

```
location $request_filename {
            if (-f $request_filename/enabledirlisting.txt) {
                            break;
            }
            autoindex off;

            if (-f $request_filename/userpasswordfile.txt) {
                            break;
            }

             auth_basic "Password protected directory!";
             auth_basic_user_file $request_filename/userpasswordfile.txt;

    }
```

However i have some issues;

- 1, It doesn't work :P
- 2, If the first condition is false, the second one doesn't execute (and i can't make multiple location directives)

I'm sure this is possible with nginx configuration. 
Or do i have to create a module/edit the nginx source code? If so, where should i start for something like this? Doesn't seem too hard to make.

Thanks in advance